# Inject CDKTF multiline token value

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, cdktf

**Context:**

- TLS provider: SelfSignedCert
- AWS provider: ECS Fargate task

```js
    const cert = new SelfSignedCert(this.stack, `${certName}-sscert`, {
      keyAlgorithm: 'RSA',
      privateKeyPem: privateKey.privateKeyPem,
      subject: [{
        commonName,
        organization
      }],
      validityPeriodHours,
      allowedUses
    });

    const containerDefinitionConfig = {
      path: {
        path: ecsJsonTaskDefPath,
      },
      args: {
        ...
        'certPem': cert.certPem,
        ...
      }
    };
```

If I try to run it like that, I get the following error:

`Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character '\n' in string literal`

I tried using:

- `cert.certPem.replace(/\n/g', '\\n')` directly on the value -- pointless because it's a token and the `replace` function only applies to the token ref, not the value itself. So I get the same error from above.
- `Fn.replace(cert.certPem, '/\n/', '\\n')` but it's complaining with `Error: '\n' can not be used as value directly since it has unescaped double quotes in it. To safely use the value please use Fn.rawString on your string.`
- `Fn.rawString(cert.certPem)` doesn't fail but sets the env var as `"${tls_self_signed_cert.seb-alice-sscert.cert_pem}"`

Versions:

`"cdktf": "^0.9.0",`

```json
  "terraformProviders": [
    "aws@~> 3.74.0",
    "random@~> 3.1.0",
    "tls@~> 3.1.0"
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's complains about the first \n in the replace function: `Fn.replace(cert.certPem, Fn.rawString('/\n/'), Fn.rawString('\\n'))`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Schmidt! it was that indeed. the docs are a bit fuzzy about this bit. However, the second arg was _slightly_ different: Fn.rawString('\\\\\\\n') (still don't know why I needed so many backslashes to make it work)

Comment: Escaping between so many formats is a bit weird, any ideas how one can improve the API / docs in this regard?

Comment: I'd say two things that could be beneficial are: 1) improve the error message: the second error suggesting to use Fn.rawString is a bit misleading -- I thought it was talking about the value I wanted to modify, not the replacements. 2) maybe do the escaping behind the scenes? If I read your solution, it makes sense and it's easy to understand. now having so many backslashes is mental :) hope that helps!

Comment: Cool, I added an issue for that: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/1601